How to deploy nextjs14 app on server with pm2 and apache
I built a nextjs14 app that's essentially a to do list. It sends post and get requests to a mysql database to update the database and get data.
I want to deploy the app to a rhel server and serve it through apache through a virtual host and reverse proxy. I'll use node to run the app and keep the app running using pm2 as the process manager.
My question is: what files do I need to transfer onto my server?
I ran npm run build and built everything into a .next directory. Do I just move the .next directory onto my server somewhere (such as /opt/node/app, where app is the name of my application) and run it using pm2? Do I move the whole project (node modules and all) onto my server and run npm run start?
